# Is it okay to use multiple concurrent read/write operations on the same database file but with different stores in Sembast?

Tags: database, flutter, nosql, sembast

My app has profile and work databases (and others) stored locally using Sembast DB.
Please look at the two examples below, which one is a better practice for asynchronous processes?

Example 1:

```
final profileDBPath = p.join(appDocumentDir.path, dbDirectory, 'profile.db');
final profileDB = await databaseFactoryIo.openDatabase(profileDBPath);

final workDBPath = p.join(appDocumentDir.path, dbDirectory, 'work.db');
final workDB = await databaseFactoryIo.openDatabase(workDBPath);

final workStore = stringMapStoreFactory.store('work');
final profileStore = stringMapStoreFactory.store('profile');
```

Example 2:

```
final dbPath = p.join(appDocumentDir.path, dbDirectory, 'database.db');

final database = await databaseFactoryIo.openDatabase(dbPath);

final workStore = stringMapStoreFactory.store('work');
final profileStore = stringMapStoreFactory.store('profile');
```

So notice that Example 1 is opening two different database files for each `profile` and `work`. And Example 2 is using the same `database` file for both.

The question is which one is better in terms of stability?
For coding simplicity I like Example 2 better but my worry is when in an Async operation Example 2 will crash when they write on the same file at the same time. Any ideas?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Example 2 will crash when they write on the same file at the same time

I don't know if that is something your experiment or just an assumption. Sembast database supports multiple concurrent readers and a single writer (single process and single isolate) and will properly use a kind of mutex to ensure data consistency. Concurrent writes will be serialized and should not trigger any crash. And if it does, that's bug that you should fill!

Personally, I would go for a single database, it would allow cross stores transaction for data consistency that 2 databases cannot provide.

Comment: Thank you Alex for the reply. So I got the `sembast_lock` error (or something like that) at runtime. I was assuming it is probably because of using the same file because when I use different files the error disappear. Maybe I was wrong. I will try to reproduce the issue and get back to you.

Comment: Make sure you are using the stores on a single database (one database can have multiple stores). Also make sure you are not opening the database multiple times (typically you should open it once on startup).